# Unable to close window application with user defined button and what is perfect process to call application from window service

Tags: c#, .net, service

I am new for c# developer and I tried to close my window application with following code. I hide close button of form and add user defined button to close application.

```
 private void closeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
            //Environment.Exit(1);
            //Application.Exit();
            //this.Close();
        }
```

But process still running on Task Manager. Actually I am calling this application from Window service. But application is not closing properly.

```
private void callback(Object state)
        {
    string strAppPath;
                        strAppPath = @"D:\VSPythonProject\Reminder_WApp\Reminder_WApp\bin\Debug\Reminder_WApp.exe"; //System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + 
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strAppPath);

                        ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
                        ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(strAppPath, out procInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are right ... you application started 2 times at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `ApplicationLoader` event. That call twice.

For closing application use below code :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
```

instead of

```
System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

To close running threads use:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExitThread( );
```

To close running form use :

```
this.close();
```

For console application use:

```
System.Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: Now application closing because I had mistake in service. I called application two time.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strAppPath);
I comment this line in service.

Comment: Ok. I have update my answer.